# Как получить строки на английском при вызове GetVersionInfo

Tags: c#, файлы, version

Я пытаюсь использовать `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` для некоторых исполняемых файлов Windows, например, таких как `rasapi32.dll`. Система перенаправляет такие запросы в файлы ресурсов для русского языка (`systemRoot\ru-Ru\rasapi32.dll.mui`). Могу ли я избежать этого и получить информацию из реального исполняемого файла (rasapi32.dll) с английским копирайтом, названием продукта и т.д.?

Установка для `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` и `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` значения «en-US» не помогает. Также установка для `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` и `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` значения «en-US» тоже не работает. Что мне сделать, чтобы избежать перенаправления вызова `GetFileVersionInfo()` (вызывал функцию так же непосредственно из `version.dll`) в файлы mui, а читать оригинальные exe-шники?

Воспроизвести:

```
{ 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
    FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfoUS = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rasapi32.dll"); 
}
```

`fileVersionInfoUS.FileDescription` будет содержать "***API удаленного доступа***", а в английской "***Remote Access API***", и т.п. остальные поля.

Comment: не найдя способа получения ресурсов непосредственно из exe вызовом GetVersionInfo(), получаю их через kernel32.dll FindResource(hModule, LP_NAME, LP_TYPE);
может кому пригодится.

Comment: можете оформить ответом ниже, вдруг кому пригодится

Answer (score 0):

решение проблемы (псевдокод):

```
IntPtr hModule = LoadLibraryEx(path, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
IntPtr hResource = FindResource(hModule, LP_NAME, LP_TYPE);
uint resSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
IntPtr resData = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
IntPtr ipMemorySource = LockResource(resData);
..
GetFileVersionString(ipMemorySource, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, template, codepage, "CompanyName"));

private static string GetFileVersionString(IntPtr memPtr, string name)
{
..
    if (VerQueryValue(new HandleRef(null, memPtr), name, ref memRef, out memLen))
    {
        if (memRef != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            data = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(memRef);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```